# Capturing audio and processing rythm in realtime

Tags: java, audio, real-time

I would like to capture audio and show the rythm in realtime.
Are there some examples available as how to do something like this?

I've searched the web for audio processing libraries, but I can't figure out how to get it to work, because most libs have examples for recording audio.

Please point me in the right direction.
Kind regards,
Maarten

Comment: Java isn't the most suitable approach to real-time audio. What do you mean by "showing the rhythm"? You want to detect BPM, or just plot the spectrogram of your waveform?

Comment: What is a more suitable approach for audio-processing? With showing the rythm, I mean to show the user the rythm that he has just played. An analyzer should determine the note length and get it displayed. The displaying is something what I already can, but determining the length is the hard part.

Comment: Your task is too wide, don't expect to get acceptable results besides recognising single notes of a short-noise transient sound [e.g. a snare or an handclap], with a simple threshold approach.